# Issue with json file writing format

Tags: python, json, format

I am writing output from python to json file.

What I tried is:

```
with open(r"c:\csv\file.json", "w") as f:
    ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
    #ids = inst_id
    for instance in ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[inst_id]):
       #print (instance.tags)
       for tag in instance.tags:
           val1 = (tag['Value'])
           val2 = (tag['Key'])
           json.dump([{"Key": val2, "Value": val1}], f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Expected output:

```
[
  {
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "node1"
  },
  {
    "Key": "owner",
    "Value": "jhonson"
  },
  {
    "Key": "managed",
    "Value": "yes"
  }
]
```

What I get is `Invalid Output: , missing after each key`, extra `[]`s are coming for each pair:

```
[
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "node1"
    }
][
    {
        "Key": "owner",
        "Value": "jhonson"
    }
][
    {
        "Key": "managed",
        "Value": "yes"
    }
]
```

If I normally print just variables to console below is output:

```
Name,node1
owner,jhonson
managed,yes
```

Can some one suggest what wrong with my `dump` syntax?

Comment: This is what you will need, ``json.dump([{"Key": tag['Key'], "Value": tag['Value']} for tag in instance.tags], f, indent=4)``

Comment: Thanks sushant, but its printing 3 times whole output seem i am not placing your statement at right place, i just replace my dump statement with yours ..making sense ? sorry for my poor knowledge..can you suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because `json.dump()` first parameter `obj` is the object you wish to serialize as a JSON formatted stream to the file-like object ( f in your case ).
You are passing `[{"Key": val2, "Value": val1}]` within a for loop. So instead of creating a single JSON array of many objects, you are creating many JSON arrays of single objects. the `json.dump()` should happen outside the for loop and be given a constructed list of objects.

Try this:

```py
ec2_tags =[]
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
for instance in ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[inst_id]):
    for tag in instance.tags:       
        val1 = (tag['Value'])
        val2 = (tag['Key'])
        ec2_tags.append({"Key": val2, "Value": val1})

with open(r"c:\csv\file.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(ec2_tags, f, indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: superb, it works now... thank you, all mistake i have done include writing in a loop ? so python dictionary format always convers to arry type in json ?

Comment: Yes, that's it! The conversion is Python dict -> JSON object , Python list -> JSON Array, Python tuple -> JSON Array.

Comment: When writing python output to txt or csv line by line, i used to open file first --> then i will put loop and then write line by line but i guess this is not case for json file, which i need to put it out of loop and write all at once ? sorry so many silly doubts...just wanted to know from experts

Comment: It depends on the situation. in this case yes it's better to build a list and use the `json.dump()` function. In CSV cases you can do a similar thing with the `CSV` https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**:

It might be easier to append your individual dicts to a list and then dump the whole thing to JSON:

```
for instance in ec2.instances.filter(InstanceIds=[inst_id]):
    keys = []
    for tag in instance.tags:       
        val1 = tag['Value']
        val2 = tag['Key']
        keys.append({val1: val2})

with open("data_file.json", "w") as write_file:
    json.dump(data, write_file, indent=4)
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but no luck, it now like below, still its not giving valid json , is missing between each key {
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "node1"
}{
    "Key": "owner",
    "Value": "jhonson"
}{
    "Key": "managed",
    "Value": "yes"
}

Comment: thank you , this is also nice solution given...i just need to add ec2_tags.append({"Key": val2, "Value": val1}) instead of keys.append({val1: val2}) like Morgan mentioned below..